# Boolean value is not getting displayed in the component after parsing the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am getting the response from my backend as JSON and using it to display it in the component .I have used JSON.stringify to convert my JSON to string.

Below is the JSON response which I am getting now:
{
        "invoiceNo": 12324,
        "transId": "34567890",
        "status": true
    }
where status is a boolean value.If i use console.log to print this value,i am getting the value as true/false but when rendering in the component,it is coming blank.

How to fix this error?

Below is my code snippet:

```
handleSubmitInvoiceXml =e=>{
    console.log("*******************inside 
    handleSubmitInvoiceXml***************");
   let url = "http://localhost:8080/postInvoiceXml";
    fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.invoiceXmlBody),
     })
     .then(res => res.json()).then(data=>
      {
    this.setState({items:data});
//Here I am getting the value of status.
    console.log(this.state.items[0].status);
    console.log("response========="+JSON.stringify(data));
       if(data===undefined){
         this.state.invoiceResultFlag=true;
           }
    else{
          this.state.invoicedisplayFlag=true;
      }
    }
  )


} 

   render() {
        <div  className= 
    {this.state.invoicedisplayFlag?"showDisplay":"hide"}>
          {this.state.items.map((item,i) => (
            <div>
            <h2>Invoice No is: {item.invoiceNo}</h2>
             <h2>Transaction id is: {item.transId}</h2>
//Here not getting any value(blank)
               <h2>Status: {item.status}</h2>
             </div>
                   ))}
           </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't render booleans. Cast it to string with:

```
String(item.status)
```

Or (maybe better), conditionally render something else:

```
<h2>Status: { item.status ? 'OK' : 'Failed' }</h2>
```

Comment: Accepted your answer !!